# Is sscanf broken?

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to parse a string with the format `1..4`, I don't want to parse these as strings, they could be anything.

However using `sscanf`:

```
char *str = "1..4";
char a[128];
char b[128];
int c = sscanf(str, "%s..%s", a, b);
printf("a=%s, b=%s, c=%d\n", a, b, c);
```

Gives the following output:

```
a=1..4, b=��, c=1
```

**Only one string is parsed? Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in `sscanf`?**

If I remove the dots:

```
char *str = "1 4";
char a[128];
char b[128];
int c = sscanf(str, "%s %s", a, b);
printf("a=%s, b=%s, c=%d\n", a, b, c);
```

I get:

```
a=1, b=4, c=2
```

Which is what I'd expect in the first example.

From the documentation `.` is not specified as a format character.

Changing the format string to parse as integers instead works as well:

```
char *str = "1..4";
int a;
int b;
int c = sscanf(str, "%d..%d", &a, &b);
printf("a=%d, b=%d, c=%d\n", a, b, c);
```

Gives:

```
a=1, b=4, c=2
```

Comment: @AnT Suggest removing [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38386149/is-sscanf-broken#comment64182187_38386149) as it is not about the post, but the poster.

Comment: As soon as you ask the question "Is a really solid, stable and commonly used piece of software broken?", the answer is almost always "No. Your usage of it is".

Comment: A lesson you should learn now and learn well: When you find yourself suspecting that a compiler or operating system has a bug, stop and think again because you are wrong. Now give up the nice fantasy and go find **your** bug.

Comment: `sscanf` doesn't do regular expressions, it does greedy matching. The first `%s` grabs as much as it can match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manual for `%s` when used in `sscanf()` is:

> Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters; the next pointer must be a pointer to character array that is long enough to hold the input sequence and the terminating null byte ('\0'), which is added automatically. The input string stops at white space or at the maximum field width, whichever occurs first.

Without providing more specific information to `sscanf()` about the nature of the strings you are trying to extract, what you are trying to do cannot simply work with `sscanf("%s")`.

My suggestion is since you don't want your first scanned argument to contain any periods, then use the `sscanf("%[]")` conversion to specify what is not allowed:

> Matches a nonempty sequence of characters from the specified set of accepted characters; the next pointer must be a pointer to char, and there must be enough room for all the characters in the string, plus a terminating null byte. The usual skip of leading white space is suppressed. The string is to be made up of characters in (or not in) a particular set; the set is defined by the characters between the open bracket [ character and a close bracket ] character. The set excludes those characters if the first character after the open bracket is a circumflex (^). To include a close bracket in the set, make it the first character after the open bracket or the circumflex; any other position will end the set. The hyphen character - is also special; when placed between two other characters, it adds all intervening characters to the set. To include a hyphen, make it the last character before the final close bracket. For instance, [^]0-9-] means the set "everything except close bracket, zero through nine, and hyphen". The string ends with the appearance of a character not in the (or, with a circumflex, in) set or when the field width runs out.

If you know you are willing to accept any string that does not contain a period then try something like the following that excludes periods:

```
char *str = "1..4";
char a[128];
char b[128];
int c = sscanf(str, "%[^.]..%s", a, b);
printf("a=%s, b=%s, c=%d\n", a, b, c);
```

Comment: `printf("a=%s, b=%s, c=%d\n", a, b, c);` before testing `c` can easily lead to UB.

Comment: About `%s`, answers omits the important  "Input white-space characters ... are skipped, ...".

Comment: @chux It's in the second line: "Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters"

Answer (score 2):

The `%s` specifier stops reading at the first non-leading whitespace it sees. It's stated in the docs [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) (scroll down to the "s" row):

> Any number of non-whitespace characters, stopping at the first whitespace character found. A terminating null character is automatically added at the end of the stored sequence.

Comment: Better to cite quotes origin.  The C11 spec does not use "stopping at the first whitespace " as that misleads.  See [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38386149/is-sscanf-broken#comment64182296_38386219)

Comment: @chux changed to say "non-leading whitespace" instead of just "whitespace"

Answer (score 1):

`%s` terminates at the first whitespace, any other format characters are ignored.

Instead I should've used `%[^.]` which will read all characters until the `.`:

```
char *str = "1..4";
char a[128];
char b[128];
int c = sscanf(str, "%[^.]..%s", a, b);
printf("a=%s, b=%s, c=%d\n", a, b, c);
```

Which gives the expected behavior:

```
a=1, b=4, c=2
```

Comment: "`%s` terminates at the first whitespace" mis-leads.  `"%s"` _first_ skips over leading white-space - does not terminate.  Then it scans non-white-space,  terminates at the first _following_ whitespace.  Using `"%s"` without a limiting wide is often weak code.

Comment: `printf("a=%s, b=%s, c=%d\n", a, b, c);` before testing `c` can easily lead to UB.

Comment: @chux `c` is an int. How could any int value cause UB with `%d`?

Comment: If `c != 2`, the the contents of `b` is not defined.  If `c < 1`, the the contents of `a` is not defined. The UB comes from printing those.

Comment: initialization with `char a[128] = "";` etc. will avoid that UB

Comment: Be aware that `[^.]` will fail if the next character to be scanned is a `.`, because no input specifier can match 0 characters. Also, `[` does not skip whitespace, so you probably want to put a space before the %.